# Regex to capture part1 and part2 only from url

Tags: javascript, regex

Sample Url:https://mywebsite.com/part1/YYYY/MM/DD/part2/part3/index.html

How to get part1 and part2 if date value is residing between part1 and part2.
I am using regex but it giving complete values from urls:
Regex: `/\/.+\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/.+/`

What I am expecting after using regex:-
val = `part1/YYYY/MM/DD/part2`

Answer (score 0):

Change `.+` for `part1` and `part2` to more restrictive `[^\/]+`:

```
\/[^\/]+\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/[^\/]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SoIA48/1

Comment: Thanks @dmitry-egorov , That what I was expecting

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex `/[a-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/(\d{2}\/){2}[a-z0-9]+\//`

```js
var url="https://mywebsite.com/part1/2017/03/27/part2/part3/index.html";
var re=/[a-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/(\d{2}\/){2}[a-z0-9]+\//;
var match=re.exec(url)[0];
console.log(match);
```